# Android Google login generate same expired token

Tags: android, google-oauth, access-token, google-signin

I am trying to login from google account and getting token using acct.getIdToken(). 
First time I get a valid token but after its expire time when I try to re-login it gives me invalid token. Token is expired so i have done logout as well as revoke but still it gives same expired token. I verified it from https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=

Please note this problem is occurring only in few mobile devices, It looks like bug on Google side, it works normally for most of users

Process of login and getting result is given below

```
Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
```

onActivityResult code

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  

    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
 if (result.isSuccess()) {
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
            Log.e(TAG, " token " + acct.getIdToken());
```

SignOut and revoke code called when token is expired

```
 private void signOut() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                        new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResult(Status status) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "SuccesFully Logout ");
                            }
                        });
            }
            Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                    new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(Status status) {
                            // ...
                        }
                    });
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have not tried or checked, however, pls read https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInApi#constant-summary , perhaps at `if you use the ID token expiry time to determine your session lifetime, you should retrieve a refreshed ID token, by calling silentSignIn...` to see if it can help or not

Comment: any solution regarding issue?